# TestNG's getCurrentInvocationCount() is too high?

Tags: java, count, testng, invocation

I have a test listener class using  `extends AbstractWebDriverEventListener implements ITestListener, IInvokedMethodListener`

in `beforeInvocation` a call to `ITestNGMethod.getCurrentInvocationCount()` returns 0
in `afterInvocation` a call to `ITestNGMethod.getCurrentInvocationCount()` returns 2

it's only one test, so why is the count at 2 after the invocation has finished?
shouldn't it be 1?

i set a breakpoint to `incrementCurrentInvocationCount()` of `org.testng.internal.BaseTestMethod.java` and it's called once in `IvokeMethodRunnable.java` and then again in `Invoker.java` when the testNG method has finished.

so an invocation count of 2 means it was called 1? and 4 it was called 2?? :)